# Values not being passed properly to a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am relatively new to react, so this might be a simple issue.  And apologize in advance if the title is not accurate.

I am trying to do a protected route with react-router-dom.  I thought that I had code correct, but for some reason, probably an ID-10-T error on my part, when a user is logged in and PrivateRoute is called the auth information is not being passed correctly.  Below is my code and a snip of the console log when /dashboard route is hit.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Redirect,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";

import './App.css';

import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import NoMatch from "./pages/NoMatch";
import Signin from "./pages/Signin";
import Signup from "./pages/Signup";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: null,
      loggedIn: false,
      username: null
    }

    this.getUser = this.getUser.bind(this)
    this.componentWillMount = this.componentWillMount.bind(this)
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getUser()
  }

  getUser() {
    axios.get('/api/auth/user')
      .then(res => {
        console.log('Get user response: ')
        console.log(res.data)
        if (res.data.user) {
          console.log('Get User: There is a user saved in the server session: ')
          console.log(res.data.user)
          this.setState({
            isAuthenticated: true,
            loggedIn: true,
            username: res.data.user.username
          })
          console.log("this.state.isAuthenticated value:")
          console.log(this.state.isAuthenticated)
        } else {
          console.log('Get user: no user');
          this.setState({
            isAuthenticated: false,
            loggedIn: false,
            username: null
          })
          console.log("this.state.isAuthenticated value:")
          console.log(this.state.isAuthenticated)
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error fetching authorized user.');
        console.log(err)
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/signin" component={Signin} />
              <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
              <PrivateRoute
                authed={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                path="/dashboard"
                component={Dashboard} />
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) {
  console.log("PrivateRoute")
  console.log("authed value:")
  console.log(authed)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => (authed === true)
        ? (<Component {...props} />)
        : (<Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/signin',
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />)}
    />
  )
}

export default App;
```

Console output:

```
PrivateRoute
authed value:
null
Get user response: 
{user: {…}}
Get User: There is a user saved in the server session: 
{id: 1, firstname: "xxxx", lastname: "xxxx", username: "xxxx", email: "xxxx@xxxx.com", …}
this.state.isAuthenticated value:
true
```

It appears that PrivateRoute is getting processed before componentWillMount, but I'm not sure how to prevent this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you might need to address in your code.

1. You don't have to bind `componentWillMount` or any life cycle method.
2. Change  `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount`. It's a good practice to make api calls after the component in mounted as `componentWillMount` will be invoked before the `App` component is mounted.
3. `PrivateRoute` will be invoked only when `App` component's render method is invoked. But since all API calls are async, `App` component's render method will be invoked even before API call succeeds because all API calls are async in JavaScript. And when the API call succeeds, the state will be updated and `App` component will be re-render with updated state.

Here's an updated code that addressing the points mentioned above.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: false, // change null to false
      loggedIn: false,
      username: null
    }

    this.getUser = this.getUser.bind(this)
    // this.componentWillMount = this.componentWillMount.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUser()
  }

  getUser() {
    axios.get('/api/auth/user')
      .then(res => {
        console.log('Get user response: ')
        console.log(res.data)
        if (res.data.user) {
          console.log('Get User: There is a user saved in the server session: ')
          console.log(res.data.user)
          this.setState({
            isAuthenticated: true,
            loggedIn: true,
            username: res.data.user.username
          })
          console.log("this.state.isAuthenticated value:")
          console.log(this.state.isAuthenticated)
        } else {
          console.log('Get user: no user');
          this.setState({
            isAuthenticated: false,
            loggedIn: false,
            username: null
          })
          console.log("this.state.isAuthenticated value:")
          console.log(this.state.isAuthenticated)
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error fetching authorized user.');
        console.log(err)
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/signin" component={Signin} />
              <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
              <PrivateRoute
                authed={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                path="/dashboard"
                component={Dashboard} />
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) {
  console.log("PrivateRoute")
  console.log("authed value:")
  console.log(authed)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => (authed === true)
        ? (<Component {...props} />)
        : (<Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/signin',
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />)}
    />
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I made the changes that you recommended, but I'm still getting the same results when hitting the PrivateRoute.   When hitting the main landing page ('/') the console log shows that there is a user logged in, but when going to dashboard it is showing as no user logged in.   Any suggestions?